# Select where..in using Spring jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two tables:

Item table representing item with some values

```
table Item(
  id,owner,name....
)
```

and "view table" representing view of the item by user

```
table ItemView(
  id, item, user_id...
)
```

Now i have @Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "public")
public class ItemEntity {
         @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;
```

}

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_view", schema = "public")
public class ItemViewEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

I am using `JPARepositorires`:

```
public interface ItemViewRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemViewEntity, Long> {
 ....
}
```

And i want to retreive top 4 viewed items of user. If i was using pure sql i could write something like:

```
`Select * from Item u where u.id in (
     Select  item from item_view  group by item order by count(*) desc limit 4
 ) and u.owner = ...`
```

How can i do this nested query using `JPA repository`?

Comment: Hope it helps , - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results

Comment: Limit isnt really the problem i think, problem is the inner select

Comment: You can use `@Query(native = true)` to implement [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)